# How to "flush" Objective-C HTTP session IDs? (Force logout from tumblr)

Tags: iphone, ios, session, tumblr, logout

I made a Tumblr Oauth API, and implemented an unlink function for the user.
The only problem that Tumblr still remain logged in.

I want to reset the session somehow. 
I've heard that session IDs are handled somewhere automatically by Cocoa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are the session id is stored in a cookie.  Use `NSHTTPCookieStorage` class to remove it:

```
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
```

You can find the cookie for the session id by using

```
    NSArray *allCookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
```

and iterating the `allCookies` array looking for the matching `domain` and `path` values.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, something like that, thanks. Just added a filter for tumblr cookies for safety.

```
for (NSHTTPCookie *eachCookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies])
    if ([[eachCookie domain] hasSuffix:@"tumblr.com"])
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:eachCookie];
```